# getting count of the same price grouping by the same transaction id

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to get the count of all prices with the same transaction type id , but i'm getting error with that , don't know the reason .

here's my code :

```
$Query =TableRegistry::get('Transactions')->find()->select('Transactions.price','Transactions.transactions_type_id')
    ->contain('TransactionsTypes');
 $Query->select([ 
              'Transactions.price' ,
              'count' => $Query->func()->count('*')
            ])  
          ->group('Transactions.transactions_type_id');
```

and if i'm going to print it , getting me that error :

> 100
>   \plugins\Budgets\src\Controller\PagesController.php (line 143)
>   object(Cake\ORM\Query) {

```
'(help)' => 'This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it.',
'sql' => 'SELECT Transactions.price AS `Transactions__price`, (COUNT(*)) AS `count` FROM transactions Transactions LEFT JOIN transactions_types TransactionsTypes ON TransactionsTypes.id = (Transactions.transactions_type_id) GROUP BY Transactions.transactions_type_id ',
'params' => [],
'defaultTypes' => [
    'Transactions__id' => 'integer',
    'Transactions.id' => 'integer',
    'id' => 'integer',
    'Transactions__transactions_type_id' => 'integer',
    'Transactions.transactions_type_id' => 'integer',
    'transactions_type_id' => 'integer',
    'Transactions__financial_year_id' => 'integer',
    'Transactions.financial_year_id' => 'integer',
```

Which 100 is the value of the first only column of the price with the same transaction type !
So how to get the count of all prices with the same transaction type id ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you read what the debug output says at the very beginning? "_This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it._"

Comment: Yes , but how can i execute it ?

Comment: Okay , now i understand you , I have make this 
 foreach($Query as $postObject) {
     echo $postObject->count;
    
}
and that back with me with  array of the count of all the same transaction type , can you help me to get the sum of each count of them , 
Meaning the transaction type with 1 having price ( 100 , 200) 
so i get 300 the total .
and transaction type with 2 having price ( 400 , 300 ) 
so i will get the total is 700 .